# How to mount/format fat32 partition so that I can WRITE on them?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am trying to format a partition `/dev/nvme0n1p4` as fat32 on `~/Work` so that I can WRITE on it. But when I try to write e.g.

```
 touch Work/test.tst
```

I get an error

```
touch: cannot touch 'Work/test.tst': Permission denied
```

It is mounted as

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 32768 Jan  1  1970 /media/Work/
```

and doing

```
sudo chown alex:alex /media/Work/
```

gives error

```
chown: changing ownership of '/media/Work/': Operation not permitted
```

I did a check with `sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p4` but that seems to be ok?

What else can I do?

Comment: You need to mount it with `fmask`/`dmask`/`umask` and `uid`/`gid` set like in https://askubuntu.com/a/956072/158442

Comment: NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/nvme0n1p4': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/nvme0n1p4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: You still need to mount it as FAT32 partition (type `vfat`), just use those options in addition

Comment: `sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,umask=007,exec /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/Work/
` seems to work maybe

Comment: That seems to work, but somehow now ubuntu is crashed. I cannot boot it anymore....

Comment: Did you edit `/etc/fstab`? If not, the change wouldn't be permanent and have no effect on booting

Comment: Yes I edited /etc/fstab. That might be the reason ubuntu does not boot anymore...

Comment: Then you will need to boot into recovery mode (or use a live USB) to fix it