# How to fix fstab entry to mount a partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

On ubuntu 22.04.4 I am trying to mount a partition as read/write. The following command seems to work:

```
sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,umask=007,exec /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/Work/
```

but I want to add it so `/etc/fstab` so it is mounted automatically. The following fstab entry however does not work:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/Work/ fat32 rw,user,uid=1000,umask=007,exec 0 0
```

It will make the system go to emergency state. How to fix the fstab entry?

Comment: The [mount type is`vfat`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508715/how-to-mount-format-fat32-partition-so-that-i-can-write-on-them#comment2647182_1508715), not `fat32`

Comment: and for ntfs the mount type is ntfs? Or something else?

Comment: It depends on the kernel version. In 5.15, they added a new NTFS driver, for that the type is `ntfs3`. Before that it was `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: how to find the kernel version?

Comment: `uname -a` gives you the kernel version

Comment: See #3, mount by device not recommended, use label or UUID: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab  Good examples:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab  NTFS example: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420861&p=13865822#post13865822

Answer (score 2):

First, find out the partition type. This you can do by mounting the partition using the command that works (`sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,umask=007,exec /dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/Work/`).

Then use the command: `df -T` OR `mount | grep "^/dev/nvme0n1p4"`. Use the "Type" to create an appropriate entry in the `/etc/fstab`.